# Creation of ASP.NET users in console application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am currently looking to build a console app to interact with a .NET webservice and insert AspNetUsers into my database.

I'm currently using this: https://www.codepoc.io/blog/net-core/5291/create-aspnetcore-identity-users-using-console-application

As a guide. However, I'm a little confused when it comes to the various dependencies required to successfully run the aforementioned code.

My workspace currently looks like this:

[image]

Am I correct in assuming that I may have the wrong version of AspNetCore? Am I missing something else or is this blog post out of date now? What would the best way be to insert .NET Identity users into the database using a .NET core console app - I'm equally not opposed to keeping it as a .NET Framework? Console app.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.dll` is its own dll which you can download via nuget from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/). Please add that nuget package to your solution. `Microsoft.AspNetCore` is a different dll that does not contain the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` namespace which is why you are getting the error and not able to resolve the reference.